# What is this slicing (?) tool?

Tags: equipment

I saw this tool at a yard sale today. It appears to be some sort of slicing or cutting device.

The construction however seemed fairly lightweight, I couldn't picture putting something dense, heavy, etc. through it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: When using this watch your fingers!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Phil is right, it is for slicing vegetables. Specifically it is a mandoline. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandoline

Comment: Given the wooden construction, non-stainless metal, and protruding fasteners I hadn't imagined this would be used for food.

Comment: Given the size, I'll bet "kraut slicer" specifically. To slice cabbage for sauerkraut.

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs why were you asking on Seasoned Advice if you didn’t imagine it was food related?

Comment: @Spagirl - It wasn't posted on here, it was migrated from Home Improvement.

Comment: @Tetsujin Ahh... that information doesn’t show up on the mobile app. I was very confused!

Comment: @Spagirl initially I had no idea what it was for at all (other than looking like a cutting device) but people on the DIY site were pretty confident it was for food prep. Seems like "alls well that ends well" :)

Answer (score 17):

That tool is indeed a slicer for cutting cabbage in preparation for fermenting it in a large pottery crock for sauerkraut. My mother used one very similar to make a five gallon and a ten gallon of crock full of sauerkraut every year back in the 50's and 60's.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like a vegetable slicer